# Why valueOf not called by boolean conversion?

Tags: javascript

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) - and actually every js documentation I read so far - the `valueOf` method converts the object to a primitive value. The example there is correct, it works with math operators properly.

In my current case I'd need it to use with logical operators, but it is never called by them. For example:

```
var o = {valueOf: function (){return false;}};
if (o)
   console.log("o -[bool]-> true");
else
   console.log("o -[bool]-> false");
if (!o)
   console.log("not(o) -> false");
else
   console.log("not(o) -> true");
if (o == false)
   console.log("eq(o, false) -> true");
else
   console.log("eq(o, false) -> false");
```

results:

```
o -[bool]-> true
not(o) -> false
eq(o, false) -> true
```

Why was it standardized this way? Why wasn't there a `toBoolean` method for boolean conversion?